# Query from view is extremely slow in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. (1) `ENQUIRY` , (2) `FOLLOW_UP` . I have to store data from `FOLLOW_UP` against `MAX(VISITOR_ID)` in a view. My view is created successfully and I can view data in `phpMyadmin`.

(1) `ENQUIRY` TABLE

```
$enq = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ENQUIRY (
        ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
        LONGDATE BIGINT,
        UNAME VARCHAR(200) ,
        ADDRESS VARCHAR(200) ,
        STATE VARCHAR(60) ,
        ZIP VARCHAR(20) ,
        PHONE VARCHAR(100) ,
        AGE INTEGER ,
        SEX VARCHAR(6) ,
        DOB_DATE INTEGER ,
        DOB_MONTH INTEGER ,
        DOB_YEAR INTEGER ,
        MARITAL_STATUS VARCHAR(30),
        BLOOD_GROUP VARCHAR(10),
        EMAIL VARCHAR(200),
        IS_MEMBER VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT 'NO' ,
        REF_SOURCE VARCHAR(150) ,
        REFERENCE VARCHAR(150),
        LAST_FOLLOWUP BIGINT DEFAULT 0,
        CREATE_BY VARCHAR(100),
        CREATE_ON BIGINT,
        SERVER INTEGER DEFAULT 0)";
```

(2) `FOLLOW_UP` TABLE

```
$enq = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FOLLOW_UP (
    ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    VISITOR_ID BIGINT ,  
    VISITOR_NAME VARCHAR(200) ,  
    LONGDATE BIGINT ,  
    FEED_BACK VARCHAR(200) ,              
    NEXT_CONTACT BIGINT ,     
    FEED_BACK_SUMMARY VARCHAR(80) ,  
    FOLLOWUP_BY VARCHAR(80),  
    SERVER INTEGER DEFAULT 0)";
```

My view is as follows:

```
$enq = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW F_TOFOLLOW 
AS SELECT 
FOLLOW_UP.ID, 
FOLLOW_UP.LONGDATE, 
FOLLOW_UP.VISITOR_ID, 
ENQUIRY.UNAME, 
FOLLOW_UP.FEED_BACK, 
FOLLOW_UP.FEED_BACK_SUMMARY, 
FOLLOW_UP.FOLLOWUP_BY, 
FOLLOW_UP.NEXT_CONTACT, 
ENQUIRY.CREATE_BY, 
ENQUIRY.IS_MEMBER 

FROM FOLLOW_UP 
INNER JOIN ENQUIRY ON FOLLOW_UP.VISITOR_ID = ENQUIRY.ID 
WHERE FOLLOW_UP.ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM 
FOLLOW_UP F WHERE F.VISITOR_ID = FOLLOW_UP.VISITOR_ID)";
```

Now I am trying to run query from the view:

```
$Q = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOFOLLOW FROM F_TOFOLLOW";
```

Any Query I try to execute is very very very very slow. Even most of the time I get:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

Some suggests me to update `max_allowed_packet` in mysql config but there is no way to do so in a shared hosting.

Similar views are running fine. What is wrong with my code?  Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: for performance issues you have to show us the tables indexes and the queries explain plans

Comment: for readability please use lower case for table names and column names

Comment: Longdate? Wassat?